# Cheeriojs retrieve all text and attributes from select/option

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, cheerio

I have the following code in a web page, I have to retrieve from the second `select` all the `option` texts and attributes to put them in a variable.

I tried like this but it's not working, no array of elements is created, where am I going wrong?

Page web:

```html
<select name="type" id="search-type">
   <option value="value0">Title0</option>
   <option value="value1">Title1</option>
</select>

...


<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
   <option value="value0">Titleo</option>
   <option value="value1">Title1</option>
   <option value="value2">Title2</option>
   <option value="value3">Title3</option>
</select>
```

Code:

```js
const eps = $('select')
        .find('option')
        .each((_, op) => ({
          ep: $(op).text(),
          url: $(op).attr('value'),
          select: 1,
        }))
.slice(2);
console.log(eps);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, the .each() method doesn’t return anything, so your `eps` variable wasn’t being assigned an array of objects. You could try something like this using jQuery:

```
const options = $('select:eq(1) option').map(function() {
  return {
    text: $(this).text(),
    value: $(this).val()
  };
}).get();

console.log(options);
```

Or using vanilla JavaScript:

```
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1];
const options = Array.from(select.options).slice(1).map(function(option) {
  return {
    text: option.text,
    value: option.value
  };
});

console.log(options);
```

Comment: `:eq(1)` gives problems, perhaps because it runs on react-native, in the end I did this: ```const options = $('select option').map((_, i) => ({ label: $(i).text(),
value: $(i).attr('value'), select: $(i).attr('selected') === 'selected',
 })).slice(2).get();```